# How to use R to calculate time gaps in scoring goals in soccer

Tags: r

I would like to get a numeric vector of time gaps between goals scored by a soccer team

```
df <- data.frame(game=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7),goaltime=c(NA,35,51,NA,NA,2,81,90,15))
```

NA indicates no goal was scored by the team in that game. The earliest a goal can be scored in a game is 1

Each game has a total time of 90 minutes so the output vector should be

```
c(125,106,221,79,9,15,75)
```

Comment: Important to note that you aren't accounting for injury time. If you had another field named `gameminutes` you could similarly calculate the gap in goals using @nicola's example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
diff(c(0,setdiff(90*(df$game-1)+df$goaltime,NA),90*max(df$game)))
#[1] 125 106 221  79   9  15  75
```

Comment: @nicola. Tx for answer. For bonus gratitude, how would I handle it for various teams if there was a team column in data.frame as well?